# Entering Values To DB With Facebook API ID Is Same For All Entries

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

When entering each `tagged_places` from the `Facebook API` the `id` and the `place_id` are entered as the same random number.

When I print the object to the screen before entry both the `id` and the `place_id` are completely different numbers than what is entered in to the DB.

These numbers should be unique from each other, but every entry in the DB from my FB user account has the same `id` and `place_id` matching each other.

Does anyone have knowledge of this issue I am having? I need the id to be unique so I can use it to identify repeat inserts into my DB.

`EDIT I notice that the number that is entered in my database for every new entry is the same number which has 10 digits. I am thinking this could be a phone number... EDIT`

This is an example of an ID from the output of the variable, 
`[id] => 10202525749041541`

And this is what shows up in the DB `2147483647`

Here is my insertion code,

```
 <?php  

$stmt = $con->prepare('
    INSERT INTO taggedPlaces
    (id, created_time, place_id, city, country, latitude, longitude, state, street, zip, name)
    VALUES
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
');

foreach($graphObject['tagged_places']->data as $data) {
if (time() - strtotime($data->created_time) < 86400) {
      $stmt->execute(array(
       $data->id,
       $data->created_time,
       $data->place->id,
       $data->place->location->city,
       $data->place->location->country,
       $data->place->location->latitude,
       $data->place->location->longitude,
       $data->place->location->state,
       $data->place->location->street,
       $data->place->location->zip,
       $data->place->name
   ));
}
}

     echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the Mysql field is set to int for `id` and `place_id`

int max value is `2147483647`

And I was trying to enter a value of `10202525749041541`

Solution for this problem was change the Mysql field from `INT` to `BIGINT`